# Apps that quiz you from a pair of decks instead of a single deck?

Tags: resource-request, flash-cards

I want to make one deck with grammar structures and one deck with topics and I would like an app that can randomly choose one card from the grammar structure and one card from the topic list and give it to me as a pair. For example ("the more...the more..." and "Sports")

Comment: You can use Anki. You can create one deck for your first topic and another deck for the second topic. Then you create a filtered deck that uses the `OR` operator so that it selects cards from both decks and you can change the settings of the filtered deck so that it chooses cards randomly.